# Swift ENUMS - Why is it yelling at me to implicitly unwrap in my enum initializer? It's forcing me

Tags: swift, option-type

In this example, in the Seasons enum, the initializer is forcing me to add the "!" implicit unwrap at the end of the initializer for 'self'. If I remove the "!", I get error: "Value of optional type Seasons? not unwrapped..did you mean to use '!', or '?'...

At first I thought this had something to do with using the rawValue method, and that possibly Swift was smart enough to know that a user entered value may not be an actual value so it automatically made it an optional, however, as you can see below, outside of the Seasons namespace, I have created a constant fall, and have used the rawValue method again, this time it worked perfectly without error.

So my question is, what is it in particular about this case that makes Swift create an optional when assigning to SELF, yet when I'm not assigning to SELF, Swift is totally allowing it to be fine without being an optional?

Thanks

```
enum Seasons : String {
    case fall
    case winter
    case spring
    case summer

    static var possibleCases : [Seasons] = [.fall, .winter, .spring, .summer]

    init(_ val: String) {
        self = Seasons(rawValue: val)!
    }
}


let fall = Seasons(rawValue: "fall")
```

Comment: Take a look at the type of `fall` – it'll be of type `Seasons?`. Also using `!` on an optional is not an implicit unwrap, it's *explicit*.

Comment: `init?(rawValue:)` is a failable initializer. What would you expect for `Seasons(rawValue: "⛄️")` ? (The compiler is not smart enough to translate that to `.winter` :)

Comment: @MartinR I demand an emoji natural processing compiler for Swift 4. Now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I figured it out that calling an Enum directly with the (rawValue:) method is actually a BUILT IN initializer in itself. It's as if there is an init?(rawValue: ) initializer already inside each enum, however it is built and and you cannot see it.

And I was incorrect in my question - the 'fall' constant is actually an Optional.

Comment: In Xcode, if you Option-click on `rawValue` in `let fall = Seasons(rawValue: "fall")`, you will see the signature of the initializer.

Comment: It's the [`RawRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/rawrepresentable) protocol that  provides the `init?(rawValue:)`. Enums with raw values implicitly conform to it.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Self-answers take longer to accept than normal answers (1 or 2 days IIRC)